# How to implement stun with python

Tags: python, websocket, nat, stun

I have a raspberry pi, which is setup as a audio streaming server. I have used websockets and python as programming language. The client can listen to the live audio stream by connecting to the server hosted on raspberry pi. The system works well in localhost environment. Now, I want to access the server from the internet and by searching I got to know about STUN. I tried to use pystun but I couldn't get the proper port for NAT punching. So can anyone help me to implement STUN?
Note: server is listening at localhost:8000

Answer (score 1):

Just Googling for STUN Python resulted in this:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pystun

Go to the bottom of that page and you'll find a link to the source code.  Unpack it and the core STUN code is in the `__init__.py` file.

Back to your audio server.  If it's a true client/server protocol and using only a single port for all communications, you don't need STUN per se.  You just need to open a port on your NAT such that any client from the outside world can connect.  If the protocol is more complicated (ports are dynamically negotiated in a peer to peer style), then you will need something like STUN on top of a signaling protocol service that is directly connected to the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

NAT punching is used for peer-to-peer (P2P) communication and your audio streaming server seems to be a client-server implementation.

How and if this is going to work heavily depends on your NAT device (which kind of NAT is implemented). Chances are high that your NAT device has short timeouts and you need to punch holes for every client connection (from your raspberry pi).

As you stated you're using WebSockets and these are always TCP, pystun isn't going to work because pystun only supports UDP.

I'd suggest to create a port forwarding in your NAT device, tunnel your traffic using a P2P VPN or host your audio streaming server on a different network.